# cracklib allows passwords even if substring of the password is within the dictionary

Tags: 18.04, password, authentication, pam

I am using PAM and cracklib for password validation, the words defined in the dictionary of known words if used as substring of password should be rejected by cracklib and pam module.

When the word which is part of the dictionary is used in the password with additional characters more than 3 the cracklib accepts it as correct password.

Below is the example :

```
labadmin@ubuntu:$ echo "Book17" | cracklib-check
Book17: it is based on a dictionary word
labadmin@ubuntu:$ echo "Book173" | cracklib-check
Book173: it is based on a dictionary word
labadmin@ubuntu:$ echo "Book1739" | cracklib-check
Book1739: OK
```

I want it to reject "Book1739" password as well since it contains "Book" which is a word in the dictionary.

Please let me know what I can do solve this issue.

Using cracklib-2.9.7.

Comment: It is probably by design, one word from Dict and a 4-digit number can be seen difficult enough. Most default rulesets of password cracking tools won't find it. You have to ask the author about what rules and if he might make them more strict. I see, you did that already [here](https://github.com/cracklib/cracklib/issues/39) which is the right place for requests like this. Just wait a bit, last changes to the repo is 2month ago...